Doubly occupied orbitals in quantum chemistry? (openfermion.org)
I am interested in diagonalising the fermionic Hamiltonian of small molecules, such as LiH in second quantisation.
The Hamiltonian is
\begin{align}
H(R) = \sum_{ij} h_{ij}(R) a_i^\dagger a_j + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{ijkl} h_{ijkl}(R) a_i^\dagger a_j^\dagger a_k a_l
\end{align}
as usual [1].
Using the OpenFermion example code [2], I generated the molecular Hamiltonian (for R = 1.45 anstroms, four active orbitals), which is given in the following format:
() -6.7698132180879735
((0, 1), (0, 0)) -0.7952726864779313
((0, 1), (2, 0)) 0.04614563473199314
((1, 1), (1, 0)) -0.7952726864779313
[...]
((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0), (0, 0)) 0.24889540266275176
((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0), (2, 0)) -0.02307282640154995
((0, 1), (0, 1), (2, 0), (0, 0)) -0.023072826401549944
((0, 1), (0, 1), (2, 0), (2, 0)) 0.005865992881900444
[...]

which means (orbital, raising/lowering operator), e.g. ((0, 1), (0, 1), (2, 0), (0, 0)) corresponds to $a_0^\dagger a_0^\dagger a_2 a_0$ and its associated $h_{ijkl}(R)$.
The single-particle terms correspond to on-site energies and hopping, whereas the two-particle (four-operator) terms have various meanings, for example correlated hopping etc.
I am confused by terms which have two raising or lowering operators on the same orbital, such as ((0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0), (0, 0)) corresponds to $a_0^\dagger a_0^\dagger a_0 a_0$ or $\hat{n}_0 - \hat{n}_0\hat{n}_0$. Surely, such processes always evaluate to zero? (forbidden by Pauli exclusion)
In other words, why does OpenFermion bother with listing terms in the Hamiltonian which are inevitably zero? What is the purpose of these terms?
[1] McClean et al. "OpenFermion: The Electronic Structure Package for Quantum Computers" https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.07629
[2] example code
from openfermion.chem import MolecularData

# Load saved file for LiH.
diatomic_bond_length = 1.45
geometry = [('Li', (0., 0., 0.)), ('H', (0., 0., diatomic_bond_length))]
basis = 'sto-3g'
multiplicity = 1

# Set Hamiltonian parameters.
active_space_start = 1
active_space_stop = 3

# Generate and populate instance of MolecularData.
molecule = MolecularData(geometry, basis, multiplicity, description="1.45")
molecule.load()

# Get the Hamiltonian in an active space.
molecular_hamiltonian = molecule.get_molecular_hamiltonian(
    occupied_indices=range(active_space_start),
    active_indices=range(active_space_start, active_space_stop))

print(molecular_hamiltonian)

```

